# ¿Cómo seleccionar un archivo local con un comando?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy tratando de que se abra la interfaz para seleccionar archivos locales, la misma que se abre cuando se utiliza el `<input type="file"/>`  pero sin utilizar el input. requiero que mediante un comando se abra directamente la interfaz para seleccionar archivos.

E tratado de crear directamente un objeto File pero me pide dos argumentos, y no encuentro mucha información al respecto.

```
let myFile = new File(); 

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.
```

tambien trate de simular un evento click en un input que no este agregado al DOM pero tampoco funciona:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
let click = new Event('click');
input.dispatchEvent(click);
```

esperaba que esto me abriera la ventana de selección de archivos. pero no funciona.alguna idea?

Comment: Saludos. Esta en inglés; te muestra con JavaScript y con jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215771/how-open-select-file-dialog-via-js/16215950

Comment: @RobertoLeOr pero el OP no quiere crear un input sino que desde el código al ejecutarlo se construya esa funcionalidad

Comment: Usando JS no podrás abrir el cuadro de diálogo nativo para seleccionar un archivo, mi sugerencia es que uses un truco, como un `input` oculto o algo parecido. Pero directamente con JS no lo lograrás, a menos que instales algún plugin (que no sé si exista alguno para eso que pretendes). Saludos

Comment: Además, el evento click tiene que ser iniciado por el usuario, o por un manejador de otro evento iniciado por el usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente no es posible iniciar el selector de archivos mediante un evento que no provenga del usuario. incluso si el evento proviene de otro elemento, intentarlo en chrome devolverá este error en la consola:

```
File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation.
```

en mi caso necesitaba iniciar la ventana mediante un atajo del teclado así que aproveche ese evento para simular el click en un `<input type="file">`

El siguiente código es de una extensión de google:

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(async (cmd) => {
       chrome.tabs.sendMessage(idtab, {funcion:'openFile'});
});
```

contentScript.js

```
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (response, sender, sendResponse) => {
        response['funcion']()
    });

let openFile = function(){
     let input = document.createElement('input');
     input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
     input.click();
}
```

y esto me funciono muy bien!